# Good examples of web based business apps?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to get more inspiration and ideas for creating web based business applications. These apps have treeviews, tabs, grid, forms, panels..etc. I develop apps but want to improve my design skills. So I would like to look at very good looking online business apps which have good use of text and background colors, good use of a general theme across the site, good use of white space, groupings and a clean layout.

I am NOT looking for web design templates or how to design a web page using css and columns.

I want to design a business app (semi heavy use of controls) which looks polished and professional.

So if you encountered a business app site or template which you liked, please share.

Business app means something like mint.com or salesforce.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

these apps are worth
 checking out for ideas (you can sign up free accounts with all of them)

Invoicing:

- [Freshbooks.com](http://Freshbooks.com) - popular
- [Invoicemachine.com](http://Invoicemachine.com) - polished UI
- [Cannybill.com](http://Cannybill.com) - polished UI
- [Blinksale.com](http://Blinksale.com)
- [GetBallpark.com](http://GetBallpark.com) - very slick and new, saw it on reddit a few days ago

Accounting:

- [Xero.com](http://Xero.com) - polished UI, they also use lots of [ExtJS](http://extjs.com) controls (rare)
- [LessAccounting.com](http://LessAccounting.com)

Project management:

- [Basecamphq.com](http://Basecamphq.com) - popular

There is lot more at [**feedmyapp.com**](http://www.feedmyapp.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com).

Comment: Wow, there are still sites that use keyword stuffing? CRM appears twice in the page title (even before their name and tagline). "CRM" appears over 30 times on the frontpage alone (not including tooltips or "Customer Relationship Management"). It occurs twice more in the meta description, and then 10 more times in the meta keywords. But that's not nearly enough, let's include "CRM" in link titles, URLs, and even tag IDs and CSS class names. Good grief...

Answer (score 3):

Look at the pinnacle of web applications: [gmail](http://www.gmail.com).

Answer (score 1):

I was impressed with the [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) site, it has a lot of good info without being too cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zoho Suite](http://www.zoho.com/) is pretty sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding gmail, and the whole rest of Google's apps.  Bonus attention to Google Calendar, that thing is a fantastic example of a classic desktop app made *better* on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the samples here:
http://www.sencha.com/products/js/